Understanding a sentence in The Church of Dead Girls
The following is from Stephen Dobyns' The Church of Dead Girls:

In any text there is both overt and covert material that accesses different cognitive levels within a reader. That is one of those statements highly regarded in teachers' conferences that I avoid.
Dobyns, Stephen. The Church of Dead Girls. New York: Henry Holt, 1997. p. 233

I am unable to pin down the meaning of the second quoted sentence. What is the antecedent of the "that" in antepenultimate position? Does the narrator avoid:

Statements like the preceding quoted sentence in general, or
Teachers' conferences in general, or
Both in general, or
Making statements of this specific kind at teachers' conferences, or
The specific kind of teachers' conferences where such statements are made, or
Some combination of the above?

Do we have any indication about how the sentence is to be parsed? Or is Dobyns deliberately leaving this ambiguous, and if so, to what purpose? What is the evidence for any one of these possible readings over another? The proffered evidence could be internal, from other elements in the novel, or external, from Dobyns' other writing, interviews, etc.
